# How to derive: $\left(\forall x\right)\left[Lx\rightarrow\left(Mx\land N x\right)\right]\vdash\left(\forall x\right)\left(Lx\rightarrow M x\right)$

Tags: solution-verification, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm trying to derive:
$\left(\forall x\right)\left[Lx\rightarrow\left(Mx\land N x\right)\right]\vdash\left(\forall x\right)\left(Lx\rightarrow M x\right)$

I thought I was on the right track with:

$1 \hspace{5 mm}(1) \left(\forall x\right)\left[Lx\rightarrow\left(Mx\land N x\right)\right]\hspace{10 mm}A\\
1\hspace{5 mm}(2)\hspace{10 mm}   La\rightarrow\left(Ma\land N a\right) \ \hspace{8 mm}1,\forall E\\
2\hspace{5 mm}(3)\hspace{10 mm}   La \hspace{42 mm}A\\
2\hspace{5 mm}(4)\hspace{10 mm}   Ma\ \land Na \ \hspace{20 mm}2,3\rightarrow E\\
2\hspace{5 mm}(5)\hspace{10 mm}   Ma \hspace{40 mm}4, \land E4\\
1,2\hspace{1 mm}(6)\hspace{10 mm}   La\rightarrow Ma \hspace{23 mm}2,4\rightarrow I\\
1,2\hspace{5 mm}(7)\hspace{10 mm}   \left(\forall x\right)\left(Lx\rightarrow M x\right) \hspace{10 mm}6, \forall I\\
$

However, I think by assuming the antecedent in step (3) that I've done something wrong.
Is that step allowed or is there a more efficient way to derive the conclusion?
Or can anyone provide any insights that I may have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your derivation is all correct; well done!

The assumption in (3) is unproblematic because the $\to I$ rule in step 6 allows to discharges this assumption: When using $\to I$ to turn the assumption from which the succedent was derived into the antecedent of a conditional, that assumption can be dropped because the conclusion no longer depends on the truth of that assumption.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach (convenient if you doubt about the introduction of arbitrary assumptions):

$$
\begin{array}{lll}
(1)&(\forall x)[Lx\to(Mx\land Nx)]&\text{Premise}\\
(2)&La\to(Ma\land Na)&\text{\(\forall\) elimination (1)}\\
(3)&\neg La\lor(Ma\land Na)&\text{\(\to\) equivalence (2)}\\
(4)&(\neg La\lor Ma)\land(\neg La\lor Na)&\text{\(\lor\) distributive (3)}\\
(5)&\neg La\lor Ma&\text{\(\land\) elimination (4)}\\
(6)&La\to Ma&\text{\(\to\) equivalence (5)}\\
(7)&(\forall x)(Lx\to Mx)&\text{\(\forall\) introduction (6)}\\
\end{array}
$$